# Doing search by count in json with params results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rails-api

I'm trying to implement a counter filter in my json. When I access the url `api/v1/contacts?Results=2` [sic], I would like to get only two results from my json.

For this, I created two methods in my controller: an index that takes the information from the database and turns render into json, and a method that returns the number of times the json is returned.

```
class Api::V1::ContactsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :results, only: [:index]

  def index
    @contacts = Contact.all
    render json: {results: @contacts[0..@number_results]}
  end


  def results
    if params[:results]
      results = params[:results]["results"]
      @number_results = results.to_i
    else
      @number_results = 3
    end
  end
end
```

Regardless of the value entered for `results =`, the value of `@number_results` is set to `0`, so whenever I type `results = I`, get only the first result of json. If I do not type `results =` in the url, it sets `@number_results` to `3`, and shows four results on the screen.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What version of rails?

Comment: what result are you looking for?
could you give an expected outcome? It is unclear to me what result are you trying to have ?
how from the url api / v1 / contacts? u ended up result 2 ?

Comment: @whodini9 rails 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in the url you propose, "Results" is capitalized. If that is how you intend to submit it, then you'll need to search for it that way on the back end. But since all your code uses lowercase "results", we'll go with that. You should modify your url in the same way: `api/v1/contacts?results=2`.

If that's what your url looks like then the number you pass in is accessible in `params[:results]`. If you pass no parameter, then `params[:results]` will return `nil`. Don't call `#to_i` on the param before you check for its existence, because `nil.to_i` is `0`.

All that said, here's what you probably want:

```
class Api::V1::ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    number_results = params[:results] || 3
    @contacts = Contact.all.limit(number_results.to_i)
    render json: {results: @contacts}
  end
end
```

If the result of `params[:results]` is `nil`, then `number_results` is assigned `3`.

Now we use `#limit` to return only the number of contacts that was requested. This allows us to do away with the `#results` method entirely. You can also get rid of the `before_action` callback.